# How to log transform in python?

Tags: python, image-processing, transform

I Create function to log transform an image in python. Below is my code..

```
#Compute Log Only
def logTransform(c, f):
    g = c * m.log(float(1+f))
    return g

def ImgLogarithmic (img_input, coldepth):

#logarithmatic transform
inputMax = 255
outputMax = 255

c = outputMax/m.log(inputMax+1)

if coldepth != 24:
    img_input = img_input.convert('RGB')

img_output = Image.new('RGB', (img_input.size[1], img_input.size[0]))
pixels = img_output.load()
for i in range(img_output.size[0]):
    for j in range(img_output.size[1]):
        f = img_input.getpixel((i, j))
        
        r = round(logTransform(c, f[0]))
        g = round(logTransform(c, f[1]))
        b = round(logTransform(c, f[2]))
        #b = value * math.log(1 + b)
        pixels[i,j] = (r,g,b)

if coldepth == 1:
    img_output = img_output.convert("1")
elif coldepth == 8:
    img_output = img_output.convert("L")
else:
    img_output = img_output.convert("RGB")

return img_output
```

I create that function to call log transform. But, my code is not working. I think my algorithm is right. Anyone can help? Thank you

Comment: Hard to tell what your expected result is. Your indentation is invalid, you never call your functions and I guess *m* is python's math library. You can use `numpys` [`np.log1p(img_input)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.log1p.html) if your image is 2-D array-like and normalize to your desired range.

Comment: unfortunately, I learn python basic without library. So, I survive that